# Using Find in a 3D Matrix - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, replace, find

So I have a large 3D matrix (Matrix1=round(rand(100,100,3)*100);) and I need to use the Find option to pick out all the values <16 and replace them with 0. I know it's easier to use other ways, but I need to use Find.

Do I need to use this:
[I,J,K] = ind2sub(size(Matrix1),find(Matrix1)<16);

If so, I don't understand what to do with I J and K after I get them.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any particular reason why you HAVE to use `find`?

Comment: Yes. It's an assignment. I've done it 2 other ways (which were super easy) as well.

Comment: Okay, here's a tiny bit of hint/teaser - You need to use a single loop. And correction - The way you are using `find` isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

So `find` will give you the coordinates of the elements you want in a [linear index](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511), use this index to reallocate the values:

```
Matrix1(find(Matrix1<16))=0;
```